# При повороте устройства ломается AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Такая проблема, есть фрагмент в котором по клике на кнопку происходит следующее:

```
 private  void onClickUpdateDate() {
           String IpAdress = currentIp.getText().toString();
           String userName = mUsername.getText().toString();
            SrvConnectHelper srvConnecter = new SrvConnectHelper(IpAdress,userName,view);
            srvConnecter.execute();
    }
```

На макете этого фрагмента есть `ProgressBar` и `TextView`, в которых отображается текущий прогресс выполнения таска:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/pb_nomen"
    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:max="100"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_bar"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_progress_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/pb_nomen"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/pb_nomen"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:text="Товара получено: 0%"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Вот собственно нам таск:

```
  public SrvConnectHelper(String host,String username,View view){
        this.host = "http://hostname:8080/LT/ws/exchange";
        this.username = username;
        dbConnector = new dbConnector(view.getContext(),BasicSettings.Main_DB_Name,BasicSettings.Current_DB_Version);
        contextView = view;

        nomProgresBar = (ProgressBar)contextView.findViewById(R.id.pb_nomen);
        nomProgresTextView = (TextView) contextView.findViewById(R.id.tv_progress_horizontal);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        Toast.makeText(contextView.getContext(),"Подключение к серверу...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        nomProgresBar.setProgress(0);
        nomProgresTextView.setText("Товара получено: 0%");
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        SoapObject resultRequestSoap;
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,"getNomen");
        request.addProperty("Manager",username);
        HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(host,60000);
        httpTransport.debug = true;

        try {
            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            List<HeaderProperty> headerList = new ArrayList<HeaderProperty>();
            headerList.add(new HeaderProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + org.kobjects.base64.Base64.encode((username+":").getBytes())));

            httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope,headerList);

            resultRequestSoap = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
            soapScaner(resultRequestSoap);
            return "Обмен завершен!";
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("ErrorSMess",e.toString());
            return "Unable to read XML: "+e.toString();
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("ErrorSMess",e.toString());
            return "Unable to read XML: "+e.toString();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        float currentElement = values[0];
        float summaryElements = values[1];
        float currentProgres = 100/summaryElements*currentElement;
        Integer currentProgresInt = Math.round(currentProgres);

        nomProgresTextView.setText("Товара получено: " + currentProgresInt.toString() + " %");
        nomProgresBar.setProgress(currentProgresInt);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

    }

    private void soapScaner(SoapObject object){
       for(int i = 0; i<object.getPropertyCount();i++){
           if(object.getProperty(i) instanceof SoapObject) {
               Log.d("NomName",((SoapObject)object.getProperty(i)).getProperty("NomName").toString());

               publishProgress(i,object.getPropertyCount());
           }
       }
    }
}
```

Проблема в том, что когда обмен начался и полоска `ProgressBar` заполняется, если перевернуть устройство то, как я понимаю андроид перестраивает приложение и хоть сам таск продолжает выполнятся он уже не обновляет не `TextView`, не `ProgressBar`. Примечание: текст в `TextView` сбрасывается на начальный, а `ProgressBar` просто замирает. Как этого избежать? Я не пойму почему вообще это происходит? Я правильно понимаю что проблема с потерей значения в переменной  `view`,

```
new SrvConnectHelper(IpAdress,userName,view);
```

Которая инициализируется здесь:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

    private View view;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_settings, container, false);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том что при повороте происходит пересоздание `Ativity`
Необходимо в методы `onPause` и `onResume` вставить соответствующий код, который будет как-то обновлять ссылки в фоновом процессе на вновь созданные элементы.

Можно, например, в onResume выставлять ссылки на эти элементы, а в фоновом процессе использовать их, а не объекты которые переданы при его создании.

Comment: Спасибо, а если я в классе фрагмента сделаю объявлю статические переменный на UI компоненты и буду их сохранять через Bundle. В свою очередь в потоке я буду дёргать их, а не то что было передано в классе. Как Вы считаете такой метод подойдет?

Comment: Заработало!) Короче так и сделал)

Comment: Статики для этого плохо. Я бы сделал методы вне класса асинхронной задачи, которые уже разбираются какую вьюху передать.

Answer (score 4):

Передавать `View` в `AsyncTask` и/или хранить `View` в `static`-полях – очень плохие идеи, чреватые утечками памяти.

Работу с сетью можно вынести, например, в сервис, жизненный цикл которого не привязан к ЖЦ активити/фрагмента.

Для выполнения задач в фоне можно использовать такие библиотеки, как, например, [Chronos](https://github.com/RedMadRobot/Chronos/) или [Robospice](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice).

Также, в Android SDK есть [`Loaders`](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html), с помощью которых можно решить Вашу задачу.